# How to handle this: There are five api requests running parallelly and 2nd request is dependent on 4th request's response

Tags: ios, iphone

I've came across a question and I want to know better approach to that.

There are five api requests running parallelly and 2nd request is dependent on 4th request's response but all 5 requests are already running. What would be the better approach?

Need suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dispatch ground works fine.

```
//create a dispatch group
dispatch_group_t serviceGroup = dispatch_group_create();

//request 1
dispatch_group_async(serviceGroup,queue,^{
    // some work here
});

//request 3
dispatch_group_async(serviceGroup,queue,^{
    // some work here
});

//request 5
dispatch_group_async(serviceGroup,queue,^{
    // some work here
});

//request 4
dispatch_group_enter(serviceGroup);
[something startWithCompletion:^() {
    //result
    dispatch_group_leave(serviceGroup);
    //request 2
}];
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @ronan

Answer (score 0):

consider gcd:

```
 dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
 dispatch_group_async(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
     // operation 1
 });
 dispatch_group_async(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
     // operation 2
 });
 dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
     // finish
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @lee jabez